# Testing that cxf sample project java_first_spring_support works

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, cxf, sample

Basic question. 
I've compiled and deployed to a local tomcat the war file that gets created in the sample cxf project java_first_spring_support (I followed the tutorial given here but using latest versions from cxf site : http://cxf.apache.org/docs/writing-a-service-with-spring.html ) but can't figure out how to test if it's working? my tomcat manager list apps page says it's running but not sure what to do beyond that.

Can I hit it with a http request via the browser to see the wsdl? If so what url should I use beyond my 'http://localhost:8080' url?
Is there no wsdl with this project and I should just craft my own soap request? and if so what should the structure be and what url should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Well, figured it out. Went back to web.xml 101 and found my answer.

The generated wsdl is available from :-
http://localhost:8080/JavaFirstSpringSupport/services/HelloWorld?wsdl

Context of the app was : 'JavaFirstSpringSupport' (got this from my apps list page in tomcat) 
 Got the services part by refering to the url pattern element in the deployed web.xml